# infinite ajax scroll plugin and firefox

Tags: jquery-ias

I'm using infiniteajaxscroll plugin to load new content into a div and it works fine with safari and chrome. In firefox I can see that the jquery-ias code is hiding the pagination div but when I reach the end of the page nothing happens and I can't see any error in Firebug.

I also noticed that in the overflow example of [IAS website](http://infiniteajaxscroll.com/examples/overflow.html) I get the same behaviour. It loads more items with safari and chrome but not with firefox.
This is an example of my code.

HTML:

```
<div style="margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; height:100%;"  id="results">    
<div id="articles"> 
<div id="article-79" class="article">....</div>
<div id="article-80" class="article">....</div>
<div id="article-81" class="article">....</div>
<div id="article-82" class="article">....</div>
...
</div>
<div id="pagina" style="display: none;"><a class="next" href="/lista.php?p=2&amp;cod=0&amp;idl=1&amp;idt=6">Next</a></div>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
var ias= $j.ias({
container : '#articles', // main container where data goes to append
item: '.article', // single items
pagination: '#pagina', // page navigation
next: '.next',
delay : 200,
negativeMargin:300
});
ias.initialize();
ias.extension(new IASSpinnerExtension()); 
ias.extension(new IASNoneLeftExtension({
  text: 'END'      // override text when no pages left
}));
```

and [this is the guide](http://www.w3bees.com/2013/09/jquery-infinite-scroll-with-php-mysql.html) I've followed to make the php page.

**EDIT:
Fixed. For anyone having similar issue, I was using another JS script that added a "position: absolute" style on `<body>` which caused this issue.**